# Agenda de contactos y no puedo completar mi metodos modificar en java

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando crear el metodp que me ayuda a modificar un contacto de mi agenda. Estoy usando Java como lenguaje, netbeans como entrono de desarrollo y Acces como base de datos.

Estoy creando los metodos por separado ya que estoy usando una heramienta que netbeans me proporciona para crear una interfaz grafica, por lo que tengo los metodos en una clase e solo tengo instanciar los metodos

El error que tengo es el siguiente

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 Argumento incorrecto en una llamada JDBC

Es el metodo que utilizo para modificar

```
Public void Modificar(String nombre, String apellido, String domicilio, String telefono,
            String email, String fechaNac, int edad, String sexo, String sZodiacal, String personaje, FileInputStream fis, 
            int longitud){
        Connection conexion = obtenerConexion();
        if(conexion !=null){
            try{
               String query = "UPDATE Contactos SET Nombre=?, Apellido=?, Domicilio=?, Telefono=?, Email=?, FechadeNacimiento=?, Edad=?, Sexo=?, SignoZodiacal=?, Personaje=?, Foto=? WHERE  Nombre=?";
               
                       PreparedStatement instruccion = conexion.prepareStatement(query);
            instruccion.setString(1, nombre);
            instruccion.setString(2, apellido);
            instruccion.setString(3, domicilio);
            instruccion.setString(4, telefono);
            instruccion.setString(5, email);
            instruccion.setString(6, fechaNac);
            instruccion.setInt(7, edad);
            instruccion.setString(8, sexo);
            instruccion.setString(9, sZodiacal);
            instruccion.setString(10, personaje);
            instruccion.setBinaryStream(11, fis, longitud);
            instruccion.executeUpdate();
            instruccion.close();  
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Metodos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);           
        }finally{
                try{
                    conexion.close();
                }catch(SQLException ex){
                    login.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }  
    }
     
    }
```

Por otro lado tengo otro metodo donde instancio al objeto y obtengo los valores necesarios para modificarlo

```
 Metodos m = new Metodos();
        String nombre = JTFNombre.getText().trim();
        String apellido = JTFApellido.getText();
        String domicilio = JTFDomicilio.getText();
        String telefono = JTFTelefono.getText();
        String email = JTFEmail.getText();
        Date fecha = JDCFNac.getDate();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        String fechaNac = sdf.format(fecha);
        int edad = Integer.parseInt(JTFEdad.getText());
        String genero;
        if (JRBMasculino.isSelected())
        genero = "Masculino";
        else
            genero = "Femenino";
        String sZodiacal = (String)JCBSZodiacal.getSelectedItem();
        String personaje = JTFPersonaje.getText();
        m.Modificar(nombre, apellido, domicilio, telefono, email, fechaNac, edad, genero, sZodiacal, personaje,fis, longitud);
```

Por ultimo tengo otro metodo que me ayuda con la conexion a la base de datos, en teoria esta bien ya que me si me funciona con los otros dos metodos que ya he creado, que son agregar y buscar-

```
static Logger login = Logger.getLogger ( Metodos.class.getName());
    public Connection obtenerConexion(){
        Connection conexion = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            String baseDatos = "jdbc:ucanaccess:///"+System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//ContactosDBS.accdb"; conexion = DriverManager.getConnection (baseDatos, "Minato", "Namikaze");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
            login.log(Level.SEVERE, null, cnfex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR, DRIVER. \n" +cnfex);
        }catch(SQLException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(Metodos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR, CONEXION. \n" +ex);
        }                
        return conexion;
                
    }
```

Ayuda porfavor

Esto es todo complelto(En mi base de datos tengo 12 daatos diferentes, el primero es uno autnumeracion que aaigna un numero a cada registro y los demas son strings, enteros y el ultimo es una foto) :

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 Parámetro no indicado
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:256)
    at martinez.adrian.contactosdbs.Metodos.Modificar(Metodos.java:94)
    at martinez.adrian.contactosdbs.Contactos.JBMoificarActionPerformed(Contactos.java:474)
    at martinez.adrian.contactosdbs.Contactos$6.actionPerformed(Contactos.java:158)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parámetro no indicado
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.checkParametersSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.executeWrapped(ExecuteUpdate.java:65)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:208)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:50)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:253)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Parámetro no indicado
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Podrías [edit] y añadir la traza de error completa, por favor?

Comment: Hola, gracias, ya la agregue hasta el final 2

Comment: Tienes 12 placeholders (`?`)  y sólo 11 parámetros. Por eso dice parámetro no indicado. Por eso hay que leer la traza completa (ahi también dice que es en Modificar, en executeUpdate, por eso el error que nos diste al comienzo estaba cojo)

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> SQLException: Parámetro no indicado (Parameter not set)

Indica que falta definir otro parámetro, si notas, en tu query se requieren 12 parámetros:

> String query = "UPDATE Contactos SET Nombre=?, Apellido=?,
> Domicilio=?, Telefono=?, Email=?, FechadeNacimiento=?, Edad=?, Sexo=?,
> SignoZodiacal=?, Personaje=?, Foto=? WHERE  Nombre=?";

Falta el último parámetro que sería asignado a `WHERE  Nombre=?`

Comment: Gracias, si quedo listo